# (django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error) while creating custon django user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

So i have been racking my beain for literal hours trying to create a simple user model.
I believe Abstractbaseuser creates default id, email, and password columns, and I added a couple more fields.
I also added the AUTH_USER_MODEL into settings.py so I'm pretty sure all the set up should be done to at least be able to run the migration.

makemigrations works and passes, but migrate gives me that error every time.
So I think, I set up the model correctly(hopefully) but there has to be something I'm missing.

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
    from django.db import models
    
    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64, default='')
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=64)
        is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    
        def __str__(self):
            f"{'username'} {'email'}"
            return
```

Comment: I think your `__str__` method is wrong. It should be: `return f"{self.username} {self.email}"`

Comment: @JordanM. Nice catch, that was wrong and I fixed it, Though the error persists.

Comment: according to [this site](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model), `AbstractBaseUser` requires more work, so instead it recommends using `AbstractUser`. I remember doing a course where I implemented a custom User using `AbstractBaseUser`, while also creating a custom UserManager using `BaseUserManager`. I you really need that I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Nevermind about the UserManager, now that I'm looking at my code, its not actually necessary, the `Model` class sets you a manager if you don't specify one.

Comment: Are you changing the user model in a existing project? If so, check [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). Another thing could be that you're importing `User` from `django.contrib.auth.models` to create a relationship in another model, if so, you should import `settings` from `django.conf` and use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `User`.

Comment: @JordanM. Thanks a bunch, I just switched to abstractuser, and it worked out, still have no idea what caused the initial issue though.

Comment: no problem. You can check the code of `AbstractUser` and `AbstractBaseUser` to compare them and see what's missing. At first sight, it could the `PermissionMixin` mixin that's being inherited from in the `AbstractUser`.